# Data pass as objects as well as an array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I'm developing a system for manage directors in group of companies. I need to `filter` directors for companies as assigned. After I pass data from `controller` to view, when selecting companies the filter shows incorrect results.

[image]

[image]

The above results will show when I `console.log(this.directorships)` those. I think it's because for single data it'll show as an `array`. But if those multiple it'll show as `objects`.

I'm looping those inside `for` loop as follows to print results.

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.directorships.length; i++) {
     single_director = this.directorships[i].director_profile;

     finalArray.push(single_director);
}
```

**MyController.php**

```
public function activeBoard($company_id){
        $directorship =  Directorship::with(['director_profile'])
            ->where('master_data_id',$company_id)
            ->get();

        $active_directors = $directorship->where('active',1);

        return $active_directors;

    }
```

Can anyone please tell me what's the mistake I have done here? Or are there any methods to do what I expect?

Comment: can you show your controller/

Comment: *"I think it's because for single data it'll show as an array. But if those multiple it'll show as objects."* No, neither JavaScript nor the console will do that if/else. In order to help you, we'll need to see an [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Snippets support Vue.js.

Comment: try `return $active_directors->toArray()` will convert object to array. and you can perform normal array functions on it.

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran I did try that one brother. But couldn't get the result I expected. Thank you so much for your valuable time for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell from the screenshots, but `Objects` in JavaScript are not iterable using a standard `for` loop, and don't have a length property by default. You should first check whether the `directorships` is an array, and then iterate or read suitably. For example:

```
let directorships_is_array = Array.isArray(directorships);

if(directorships_is_array) {
  // ... loop through array
}
else {
  // ... perform other function on object
}
```

There are a number of ways to iterate through an object, and get an objects length. The new `for in` loops can iterate through an object. For example:

```
for(let director in directorships) {
  console.log(director);
}
```

You can also get the length of the `Object` using something like, `let directors_length = Object.keys(directorships).length` and then do something like this:

```
let number_of_directorships = Object.keys(directorships).length;

for(let i=0; i<number_of_directorships; i++) {
  // ... iterate here
}
```

Comment: I did try the last one mate. But didn't work. But I'll give a try for above. Thank you so much for helping. Appreciate it brother.

Comment: Thank you million times man. Using the second one I did what I need.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use query like this you have initialize query before the condition

```
public function activeBoard($company_id){
        $directorship =  Directorship::where('master_data_id',$company_id)->where('active',1)->with('director_profile')->get();


return $directorship;

    }
```

Comment: I did this also. But what I need was to access the data from `vue.js`. By the way thanks for the answer @monu0002